# completely free memory after the Activity is closed

Tags: android, memory

I need to **completely** free the memory which was in use by an `Activity` when the user closes that Activity. will using

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

be enough?

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve by completely freeing the memory?

Comment: my app is using lots of images and resources, so memory is a hot issue for my app! and when the second activity gets closed there is no reason to _have_ any thing related to that in memory...suggestion?

Comment: Make sure, you don't keep references to objects you do no longer need. The system will take care of the rest.

Comment: for example at start i need a reference to an `ImageView`, ImageView tmp=..... but after some moments i don't need that object any more, how to release it?

Comment: set `tmp=null` and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

By saying

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

you tell android not to keep a reference of your activity inside the back stack of activities. That's already a good start.

The only thing that remains to be done is to be sure that you don't keep a reference yourself to your activity. For instance, *don't* :

- store your activity's instance as a static data field. It would not be garbage collected as classes are not.
- store your activity's instance as a data field of a singleton. (As transitively a singleton instance is a static data field). And so on.

If you don't keep any reference to it, and add the noHistory flag, then you can be sure it will be garbage collected.

Also, note that you can use [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) with eclipse to get sure that there is no instance of your first activity as soon as you reached the second activity.